# Mysql Select Product attribute price

Tags: mysql

Sorry for my bad english)

Need help with mysql query.

There is a products table, which stores the base price for products that do not have attributes that the price depends on.

### Table: product

| product_id | product_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T-shirt_1 | 10 |
| 2 | T-shirt_2 | 12 |
| 10 | T-shirt_10 | 18 |
| 15 | Hat | 10 |

There is a table of attribute values by which products are filtered.

### Table: eav_ent

| ent_id | product_id | attr_id | attr_value_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 19 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 34 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 23 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | 56 |

### Table: eav_ent_product_price

| ent_product_price_id | product_id | price_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | T-shirt_1 size S | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | T-shirt_1 size M | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | T-shirt_1 size M with a zipper | 20 |
| 4 | 2 | T-shirt_2 size M | 12 |
| 5 | 2 | T-shirt_2 size M with a zipper | 25 |

### Table: eav_ent_product_price_attr

| ent_product_price_attr_id | product_id | attr_value_id | ent_product_price_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 19 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 19 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 19 | 4 |
| 6 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 7 | 2 | 19 | 5 |

For each product, you can separately create prices depending on the combination of attributes, for example:

T-shirt_1 size S - 10 $

T-shirt_1 size M - 15 $

T-shirt_1 size M with a zipper - 20 $

Hat - $ 10 (base price)

How can I correctly filter products and display prices depending on the selected attributes, if they exist, or just display the base price?

What I tried:

```
SELECT a.* FROM(
    SELECT p.* FROM product p 

    JOIN eav_ent en1 ON en1.product_id=p.product_id AND en1.attr_value_id=19
    JOIN eav_ent en2 ON en2.product_id=p.product_id AND en2.attr_value_id=4

    LEFT JOIN eav_ent_product_price ppi ... I don't know

    WHERE 1 GROUP BY p.product_id

) a WHERE 1
```

Comment: What is the purpose for table `eav_ent` in the query?

Comment: This is a table that stores the selected attribute values ​​for the products. In the request, for example, through eav_ent we select products with attr_value_id=19 and attr_value_id=4.

Comment: Your current join on `eav_ent` table twice returns 1 row. Is it suppose to be like that? If you're looking to return two rows of `attr_value_id=19` and `attr_value_id=4` you can do 1 join and change the second `ON` to `AND en1.attr_value_id IN (19,4)`. Is there a particular reason to `JOIN` the table twice? Here's a fiddle you can play with https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a49ce51ab5c737e28e193ee05b2b60a7 . You can edit it then click run and it will generate a new link. You can post that fiddle link into your question if you want. By the way, can you check your MySQL version?